# How do I modify a shell environment variable in swift?

Tags: swift, macos, process

How can I access one of the shell env vars when using `Process`? If I use `environment` to set them, it will change all of the env vars.

```
let task = Process()
// How do I modify PATH only instead of setting the whole dictionary
task.environment = ["PATH": "/usr/local/bin"]
```

Comment: Use the arguments property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might solve it appending on `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment` (the inherited environment) your custom path (or whatever you need):

```
let task = Process()
var environment =  ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
environment["PATH"] = "/usr/local/bin"
task.environment = environment
print(task.environment ?? "")
```

Comment: as shown above, be sure to assign to task.environment as ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment is read-only https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo/1417911-environment

Comment: unless I'm mistaken, the above updates the subprocess rather than the process. The print will output as expected. However `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

If you're here searching for how to modify `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment`, it is via a global function:

```
setenv("key", "value", 1)
```

(`1` means "overwrite")